# Uploading Windows Phone App to Windows store

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have recently developed windows phone application but im getting problem in uploading that app to windows store.
Please can any body tell me the process how to do that

Thanks in advance

Comment: At which step are you stuck right now?

Comment: Packages(upload your app to win store)

Comment: How to create app package?

Comment: Build you App in "Release mode". And the resultant "YourApp.xap" is your package

Comment: I tried to upload "App.xap". it displayed error as "You can upload only .appx, .appxbundle or .appxupload files".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone Dev Center makes it fast and easy for you to submit or update your app. Complete these two basic steps, and your app will be reviewed promptly.

[Create your app info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206733%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

What's the name of your app? Which category does your app belong in? How much do you want your app to cost? After you fill in the blanks for these and other questions, you'll be ready to upload.
[Upload and describe your package(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206723%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Upload the necessary packages for your app, fill in the relevant details (language, description, images, etc.), and submit.